# What is the best plot to show a distribution in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, distribution

I'm looking to plot the distribution of age across the different trees in the locality data.

I did the following but the graph isn't representative :

```
ggplot(tree_data, aes(x = Age.Life, fill = Tree)) + 
geom_density(alpha=.5) + 
scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1")
```

Comment: Try with `geom_histogram`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including example data in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(yourdata)`. It would help to see the chart too - it's difficult to know what "representative" means without seeing the data or output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `geom_boxplot()` distribution:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length, fill=Species)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1")
```

[image]

Or `geom_histogram()` As @akrun suggests. I've added combined with `facet_grid()`.

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length, y=Species, fill=Species)) + 
  geom_histogram() + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1")+
  facet_grid("Species")
```

[image]

And the popular `geom_violin()` plot

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length, y=Species, fill=Species)) + 
  geom_violin() + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1")
```

[image]